# trigger.io Forge API call to /should_fetch_core_instructions

Tags: trigger.io

HWhen I run the "forge build" command in the terminal I always get this message:

```
$ forge build ios
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.82
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[  ERROR] Forge API call to app/[HASH]/should_fetch_core_instructions went wrong: Unknown error
```

This worked fine in the past and I have to idea where to start looking to fix this issue.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you changed your forge version or updated your tools recently? Did you try it again on the next day to see if it was just a temporary issue?

Comment: I just updated to the latest version and the problem still persist